# How to get the last sign in IP address of the user and current sign in IP address of the user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using 'devise' gem in rails framework for authentication how to get last sign in IP address of the user and current sign in IP address of the user is it possible in a devise or any other alternatives ways to get it.

Answer (score 2):

In your controllers you can access the current ip via `request.remote_ip`.

So you could overwrite the `authenticate_user!` method of devise or just simply write your own `before_action`. This requires `current_ip` column on the `User` model.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :hit_user

  def current_ip
    # request is the object that carries all the information from the 
    # request to the controller
    request.remote_ip
  end

  private

  def hit_user
    current_user.hit!(current_ip) 
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  def hit!(current_ip)
    # use update_attribute since this happens on every request and you 
    # dont want to trigger User validations all the time
    self.update_attribute(current_ip: current_ip)
  end
end
```

This way you have the current_ip and the last one that was used for the request.

Comment: is request.remote_ip is equals to current_sign_in_ip

Comment: sure the solution still applies. You have to keep the old ip stored somewhere anyways.